# Can I transfer profile created on 32-bit FireFox to 64-bit FireFox?

Tags: windows, firefox, 64-bit

I used to use 32-bit Windows, so I currently use 32-bit FireFox. 
Can the profile be transferred to the 64-bit version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Firefox places the profile information in your user profile, this is entirely independent of bit-ness. So your profile should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

to easily backup/restore FF profiles you could use MozBackup...
http://www.mozbackup.org/